# DataForm Web Part Sorting Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, data-view-web-part

I am facing the strange issue with data form web part sorting.

After clicking on ascending/descending from the header, instead of sorting what happens is, all the groups are appearing multiple time.

And this same thing happens after every time i click on ascending/descending.

Please find the below screenshot.

**Before Sorting :**

[image]

**After Sorting :**

[image]

Anybody have any idea for this behavior of data form web part.

Thanks in advance.